# Build failed compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' on android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `RecyclerView` and `CardView` on android studio. I got the error while I run the program gradle. I'm using implementation

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

I attached image below:

[image: attached image]

I attached this line in above:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // add google() before jcenter()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}
```

but the error didn't goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this**

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (**mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes**)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the correct version as 28.0.0
just click alt-enter to get suggestions and you will get :
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

and your error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Same Version 28.0.0**

like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

else **lead to runtime crashes**

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong version of Recyclerview and Cardview. They must be same as

> android.support.appcompat.v7

Replace recyclerview and cardview with below

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Hope you understant